# CSS & HTML: Clutter elements when change floating

Tags: html, css, templates

i try to edit [this web template](https://bootstrapmade.com/demo/themes/Squadfree/) and change it to right to left. so i changed floating of header elements such as brand and navigation to opposite and a big problem accrued that wasted my many hours.
in small screen drop down menu original template is like:
[image: this image--] 
but my template is:
[image: this image--]
[and this is online link of edited template](http://tebd.ir/test/)
it is so confusing i changed many items even in JS but and no results.
how can i fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CSS rule:

```css
@media (max-width:600px)
{.nav li {position:relative; display:block;width:100%!important}
}
```

And it will be, when screen width less or equal than 600px :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PkCRM.png)

And, to change navigation button move it from  to one level up to nav element
[image]

Comment: thanks a lot. and what i must do with unwanted margin of navigation button on the left?